# Me and Alexander in Puzzlevanian cafe

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story

Some time ago I visited my old friend, Alexander, who lives in Puzzlevania, where everything is a puzzle. We went to a cafe to talk a bit. To check how well we know each other I ordered for Alexander and he ordered for me. We were provided with menus, but the prices were out of this world:

```
Coffees:    
1. Cappuccino   6.20
2. Espresso     7.40
3. Latte        2.48
4. Macchiato    6.90

Flavoured Coffees:  
1. Banana      14.86
2. Chilli       2.30
3. Chocolate    3.21
4. Orange       9.87
5. Raspberry    4.56

Pies:  
1. Apple        1.23
2. Banana       5.41
3. Peach       15.30
4. Strawberry  34.56
```

Nevertheless I knew Al loves bananas and strawberries so I chose banana-flavoured coffee and a strawberry pie for him. We kept our orders secret (written on paper passed to the waitress) until they were served.
Then the waitress came back to our table with a trolley full of food including caffe latte, cappucino, espresso, apple pie, orange-flavoured coffee, raspberry-flavoured coffee, banana pie, chilli-flavoured coffee, orange-flavoured coffee, raspberry-flavoured coffee, chocolate-falvoured coffee, espresso, apple pie, banana-flavoured coffee, strawberry pie, espresso, peach pie, macchiato for me and banana-flavoured coffee and a strawberry pie for Alexander.
She drew out an old fashioned calculator and spelled doom on Al's wallet. Then she said:
'Your friend was very kind to you. Why didn't you do the same for him, mr. Oleslaw?' and she turned away.
I felt bad that I ordered only so little for Alexander. I knew that I should have ordered at least two more things.

**Do you know which ones?**

Comment: Are *espresso* and *apple pie* repeated on purpose?

Comment: @Techidiot This is not a mistake.

Comment: *the prices were out of this world* - if you know so little about Puzzlevanian etiquette, how do you know what a reasonable price is?

Comment: @boboquack The prices were not reasonable for me, but I knew that in Puzzlevania this would be faux pas if I questioned them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The prices

> need to be interpreted as specifying paths on the keyboard of that "old-fashioned calculator". Pairs of digits that don't share a row, column or diagonal on the keyboard make a break in the path. Zeros are ignored. Separation between symbols appears not to be explicitly marked.

caffe latte, cappucino,

> `7 8 9
>   / \
>  4 5 6
>   \ /
>  1 2 3`

espresso, apple pie,

> `7 8 9
>  |
>  4 5 6
>  |
>  1-2-3`

orange-flavoured coffee, raspberry-flavoured coffee, banana pie, chilli-flavoured coffee,

> `7-8-9
>  |
>  4-5-6
>  |
>  1-2-3`

orange-flavoured coffee, raspberry-flavoured coffee, chocolate-falvoured coffee,

> `7-8-9
>  |
>  4-5-6
>      |
>  1-2-3`

espresso, apple pie,

> `7 8 9
>  |
>  4 5 6
>  |
>  1-2-3`

banana-flavoured coffee, strawberry pie,

> `7 8 9
>   / \
>  4-5-6
>  |   |
>  1 2 3`

espresso, peach pie, macchiato

> `7 8 9
>  |   |
>  4 5 6
>  |/ \|
>  1 2 3`

Our narrator should have added, perhaps,

> an espresso followed by an apple pie

so that in addition to the original

> `7 8 9
>   / \
>  4-5-6
>  |   |
>  1 2 3`

he could add

> `7 8 9
>  |
>  4 5 6
>  |
>  1-2-3`

thus saying

> AL.

Comment: I have nothing to add. Exactly what I expected. Congratulations.